# command-line 'FOR'

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

There are 3 files in 'D:\log' folder, which names are 'log1.txt log2.txt log3.txt' respectively. I want to show some infomations by using 'FOR' MS-DOS command.

```
 
set /a C=0
for %%I in (log*.txt) do ( 
  echo "%C%--%%I"
  set /a C+=1
)
```

Output strings were like this

```
 
0--log101105.txt
0--log101116.txt
0--log101117.txt
```

But, Expected outputs are like belows not aboves

```
 
0--log101105.txt
1--log101116.txt
2--log101117.txt
```

How to increase value of parameter 'C' while FOR loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /a c=0
for %%I in (log*.txt) do ( 
 echo "!C!--%%I" 
 set /a c=!c!+1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I should observe the help closely.

Answer (score 0):

vYou need to enable "delayed variable expansion" for this.

Check out the help for the SET statemen (`SET /?`). 
It explains exactly your problem

Comment: `bariable` is a boolean variable?  ;P